# Azure DevOps - Change Reason

Tags: azure-devops

With an inherited process with - we cannot modify Reason or Root Cause picklist values?  How can this actually be used by a professional organization if we cannot customize it to fit our process?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops

Comment: "The reality is we don't have plans to ever add a first class edit reason field experience. I would rather be honest with the community on that instead of letting it drag out and never act." from Microsoft itself on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-customize-wit-state-reason-in-inheritan/365937#T-N1109854

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a new state (organization -> process -> processes -> select process -> select work item type), then you can write into the reason whatever you want.

[image: Reason Field is editable]

@dan: Does this answer your question?
@cece: Is that want you meant?

As far as I know there is no other way to customize this. Also creating rules for the new created state (like 'if changed to state MyState then change value of field Reasons to anything') is not possible.

Comment: thanks for your reply, no, don't want to enter freeform text, want a dropdown list so it's consistent...

Answer (score 0):

The picklist values of Reason for the default states are not able to be modified. You could try to add a custom State or a custom work item type, the Reason can be modified when you use custom States or custom work item types.

[image]

Comment: thanks but where do you do that exactly? i don't see it when I add/edit a state with new work item type with inherited process. https://imgur.com/8ySpfVn

Comment: also how can we use rest api to get a list of valid reasons for each state?

Comment: When you change the state in the work item, you are able to modify the Reason for a custom State or a custom work item type.

Comment: thanks for reply Cece but I do not see it as per my screen shot above.  can you give exact details please?

Comment: @dan, are you using on-premise or the A.DevOps Service? they have different levels of configuration I think.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use a work around, SELECT "> Work items > {{selct your work items}} > Actions > Create copy of work items"

And be aware to choose the "reason" you want and delete previous work item after completed.

For more detail information, please refer to Azure Devops Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser